# How to use the sum() function in R - start count from other value than 0

Tags: r, sum

I'm just start to learning R and I'm a bit confused, how do I write sum from i=2 to n in R? if I use just sum doesn't it start from i=0 to n then?

Thank you

Comment: `n <- 10; i <- 2:n; sum(i) ` = 54

Comment: Maybe test it out and see?

Comment: Or if `i` is the element index of another vector, say `a <- 101:105`, we could sum the  range 102:105 with `sum(a[2:5])`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the vector that you want to sum. You can start it at any integer you want

```
n <- 5

to_sum <- 2:n
```

Then sum that

```
sum(to_sum)
```